# Swift How to refactor getting data from API?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get data from API and display it in the tableView.

Because getting data from API used multiple times in my application. So I want to make it reusable.

I create a class called `GetProducts` to get the data from API, and save it to `Posts`

```swift
class GetProducts{
    static var products = [Product]()
    static func loadProducts( _ filter: [String:String]) {
       // get data from API
       // append products to products list
    }
}
```

In the viewController, I want to fetch the products data from `GetProducts` class, and display it in the tableView

```swift
class MainViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
      @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!         

      override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           tableView.dataSource = self
           tableView.delegate = self
           GetPeoducts.loadProducts([...])
     }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return GetProducts.products.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath) as ProductTableViewCell
             cell.products = GetProducts.products
             return cell
     }


}
```

However, in the tableView, the `products` list is empty.

I cannot figure it out which step was wrong. Is there anyone can help me with logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: completion handler

Comment: reload tableview once data is successfully fetched from the api

Comment: API calls are mostly a-synchronic, yours might be as well (that part is missing). You need to apply competition handler and then reload the data on the table.

Comment: Answer would be completion handler .Completion handlers are super convenient when your app is doing something that might take a little while, like making an API call, and you need to do something when that task is done, like updating the UI to show the data. You’ll see completion handlers in Apple’s APIs

Comment: Thanks, you guys, I do use the completion handler as you suggested. It works perfectly. I will add my solution shortly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what I'm doing is using completion handler

```swift
class GetPosts{
      static var products = [Product]()
      static func loadProducts( _ filter: [String:String], completion:(([Product]) -> Void)?) {
           // get data from API
           // append products to products list
           completion?(self.products)
      }
}
```

Call the `loadPoducts` in ViewController:

```swift
class MainViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
      @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!         
      var products = [Product]()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           tableView.dataSource = self
           tableView.delegate = self
           GetPeoducts.loadProducts(/*some params*/){ (products) in
                 self.products = products
           }
     }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.products.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath) as ProductTableViewCell
             cell.products = self.products
             return cell
     }


}
```

Thank you! @rmaddy @Vanya @Aakash @Jelord Rey